# SQL Check if a file was in open status during specific timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-range

I need to look at each Month/Year for a given time frame and check to see if, during that month and year, a file was in an open status. On each file there is an open date and close date so for each file I want to check if the open date's month and year is less than or equal to each month/year in the range and then if the close date is either null or has a month/year that's greater than each month/year in the range. However, I'm stumped on how to inform the query what the current month year is that I'm looking at. My query looks like the following:

```
-- New Files
select distinct datepart(MM, ws.CaseOpenDate) as 'Month',
    datepart(yyyy, ws.CaseOpenDate) as 'Year',
    count(ws.WorksheetID) as 'Count'
into #newfiles
from LGSIntersect lgs
    join Worksheet ws on ws.LGSIntersectID = lgs.LGSIntersectID
where ws.CaseOpenDate between '01/01/2016' and '03/01/2017'
    and lgs.GroupCodeID = '307'
group by datepart(MM, ws.CaseOpenDate), datepart(yyyy, ws.CaseOpenDate)

-- Open Files
select distinct datepart(MM, ws.CaseOpenDate) as 'Month',
    datepart(yyyy, ws.CaseOpenDate) as 'Year',
    datepart(MM, ws.CloseDate) as 'CloseMonth',
    datepart(yyyy, ws.CloseDate) as 'CloseYear',
    count(ws.WorksheetID) as 'Count'
into #openfiles
from LGSIntersect lgs
    join Worksheet ws on ws.LGSIntersectID = lgs.LGSIntersectID
where ws.CaseOpenDate <= '03/01/2017'
    and (ws.CloseDate is null or ws.CloseDate >= '01/01/2016')
    and lgs.GroupCodeID = '307'
group by datepart(MM, ws.CaseOpenDate), datepart(yyyy, ws.CaseOpenDate),
    datepart(MM, ws.CloseDate), datepart(yyyy, ws.CloseDate)

-- New Investigations
select distinct datepart(MM, ws.InvestigationDate) as 'Month',
    datepart(yyyy, ws.InvestigationDate) as 'Year',
    count(ws.WorksheetID) as 'Count'
into #newinv
from LGSIntersect lgs
    join Worksheet ws on ws.LGSIntersectID = lgs.LGSIntersectID
where ws.InvestigationDate between '01/01/2016' and '03/01/2017'
    and lgs.GroupCodeID = '307'
group by datepart(MM, ws.InvestigationDate),
    datepart(yyyy, ws.InvestigationDate)

-- Ques Sent
select distinct 
    datepart(MM, qpd.PrintDate) as 'Month',
    datepart(yyyy, qpd.PrintDate) as 'Year',
    count(qpd.QuestionnairePrintDetailID) as 'Count'
into #ques
from LGSIntersect lgs
    join QuestionnairePrintDetail qpd 
        on qpd.LGSIntersectID = lgs.LGSIntersectID
where qpd.PrintDate between '01/01/2016' and '03/01/2017'
    and lgs.GroupCodeID = '307'
group by datepart(MM, qpd.PrintDate),
    datepart(yyyy, qpd.PrintDate)

select distinct
    nf.Month,
    nf.Year,
    isnull(sum(q.Count), 0) as '# of Ques Sent',
    isnull(sum(ni.Count), 0) as '# of New Investigations',
    isnull(sum(nf.Count), 0) as '# of New Files',
    isnull(sum(opf.Count), 0) as '# of Open Files'
from #newfiles nf 
    left join #ques q on q.Month = nf.Month and q.Year = nf.Year
    left join #newinv ni on ni.Month = nf.Month and ni.Year = nf.Year
    left join #openfiles opf on (opf.Month + opf.Year <= nf.Month + nf.Year) 
        and (opf.CloseMonth is null 
            or (opf.CloseMonth + opf.CloseYear > nf.Month + nf.Year))
group by nf.Month, nf.Year
```

Right now there's no way to make sure it's only summing the total files that were open during each month/year in question (unlike the "# of ques sent" and "# of new files", which calculate correctly when I remove the logic for the open files). Any hints would be greatly appreciated - let me know if I need to provide additional information. I was on medical leave for 6 months so I got very rusty at all this. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using MS SQL server

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think is the gist of the problem --
In case of New files, If the file is opened on 01/01/2016 then the result set of New files will have just one record for month of January
In case of Open files, if a file is opened on 01/01/2016 and closed date is null (I guess meaning still open), then the result set of Open files will need to have record for each month (i.e. 15 records for 15 months) since the record has been open all those months. So one file record with start date of 01/01/2016 and end date null, should generate 15 records in the result set. Whereas in case of New files, this file record will generate only one record i.e. for month of January in the result set.

So,
It would be a good idea to have

- A separate table to maintain a list of all Year-Months.
- Apply your date range filter on this year-month table.
- Using this year-month table as the master table- left outer join to
  your files table. If the year-month falls between individual file's start and and date then count as 1 . Otherwise 0.
- Aggregate/Sum the above count, with group by on Year-month. And that should give you the number of open files for each month within date range you specified.

[Edit]
Adding more detail as requested

Months Table 
MonthStartDate, MonthEndDate

Files Table
CaseOpenDate, CaseCloseDate

MonthsTable Left Outer Join FilesTable
ON 
CaseOpenDate <= MonthEndDate
AND
(CaseCloseDate > MonthEndDate OR CaseCloseDate IS NULL)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like it just might do what I need. I will give it a shot!

Comment: What criteria would I be using to join the master date table to the open files table?

Comment: Edited my answer to add more details at the bottom.